# How to evaluate "item in $ctrl.items" in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a custom component in angular js.
I'm trying to evaluate `"item in $ctrl.items"` attribute which sets a variable name called `"item"` for every item in the `"$ctrl.items"` array.
Basically the same way ng-repeat does to an array.

Comment: You might find some hints here ~ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L367

Comment: They're doing regex, thanks